# The slope of a curve when $x = 1$ and $y = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

The surface with equation $z = x^{3} + xy^{2} $ intersects the plane with equation $2x-2y = 1$ in a curve. What is the slope of that curve at $x=1$ and $ y = \frac{1}{2} $

So I put $ x^{3} + xy^{2} = 2x - 2y - 1 $

We have $ x^{3} + xy^{2} - 2x + 2y + 1 $

Do I then differentiate wrt x and y simultaneously?

I know how to differentiate at a point with directional derivatives. But how do I go about the above question considering the fact that direction isn't mentioned.

Maybe I'm going completely down the wrong route... any help is hugely appreciated !

Comment: So, this is just a planar curve. How about just implicit function differentiation?

Comment: @ValerySaharov Is z taken out of the equation altogether, are we just left with x and y ?

Comment: @ValerySaharov Also, does this not mean we can only differentiate wrt one variable?

Comment: Are you sure that you found the intersection right? The plane is parallel to z-axis. So z-coordinate should change along y = x - 1/2. As soon as you're in the plane, you can differentiate the curve using, say, implicit function differentiation.

Comment: Well, that's what I was wondering.. have I made a mistake above. If so could you show me the right way to approach it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but the algorithm may be as follows:

- Rotate the axes so that the plane boils down to one parallel to both $z$ and, say, "new" y-axis, namely, $v$:

$$ (u, v)^T = R(x, y)^T, (u, v)^T = R^{-1}(x, y)^T $$

- Translate it to the origin so that the plane coincides with the $(v, z)$-plane
- Substitute $u=0$ into the equation $z = f(u, v)$
- Differentiate w.r.t. $v$

Update: another algorithm is to parametrize the intersection curve using, say, $x=t$, $y=t-\frac{1}{2}$, $z=f(t)$, and find the velocity vector at the desired point.

Answer (score 0):

let me  parametric equation for the plane $x = 1 + t, y = 1/2 + t$ then the curve on the surface $z = x^3 + xy^2$ is $$z = (1+t)^3 + (1+t)(1/2+t)^2 = 1 + 3t + 3t^2 + t^3 +1/4 + 1/2t+t^2 +1/4t+ 1/2t^2 + t^3\\ =5/4+15/4t+\cdots $$  so the tangent vector at the point $(1, 1/2, 5/4)$ is $(1, 1, 15/4).$